# Can somebody explain me this recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def name(n):
    if n>0:
      name(n-1) 
      name(n-1)
      print(n)
      
name(5)
```

How this is generating  1,1,2,1,1,2,3.....so on output? like which function is working first or both working simultaneously and how n is printing like this.

Comment: It is interesting to work this out by just looking at the numbers, but you can add more descriptive messages to the function body and it will become more obvious. For example,  add `print('called with', n)` as the very first line in the function. For even more transparency, add `print('exiting the call with', n)` at the very bottom. It's important that both calls are outside the `if` statement.

Comment: It happens all in order. The first call to `name(n-1)` happens, and inside that call, the first call to `name(n-1)` happens, and so on down until `n==0`. Follow the code with pencil and paper. It's not hard, just tedious.

Comment: You could try to play - `run` this code in https://pythontutor.com/ and watch step-by-step (tot. 284 steps!)

Answer (score 2):

Try with smaller numbers. For example if you run `name(1)` it will just print 1. becase two functions in the middle will just return. If you write `name(2)` it will run the first inner funtion, which will print 1(like I said previously). Second function will do the same and last statement will print 2. So the output is `1 1 2`. If you go for `name(3)` it will just the same as `name(2)` but twice and will print 3 at the end `(1 1 2) (1 1 2) 3`. `name(4)` will do `name(3)` twice and print 4 at end and so on

Answer (score 1):

Another way to lok at this is in reverse. eg. you look at the smallest number:

- `name(0)`: Prints nothing, thus ""
- `name(1)`: calls name(0) twice, and then prints `1`, thus `"1"`
- `name(2)`: calls name(1) twice, and then prints `2`, thus `"112"`
- `name(3)`: calls name(2) twice before it prints `3`, thus `"1121123"`
- `name(4)`: calls name(3) twice before it prints `4`, thus `"112112311211234"`
- `name(5)`: calls name(4) twice before it prints `5`, thus `"1121123112112341121123112112345"`

Finally the clue is that there is no spcial treatment of functions that recurse. Every call to a function, even `print`, will wait for that to return and then continue on the next line as long as the statement didn't include a `return` in which it would return. that name(5) ends up calling itself with different versions of `n` at different levels is no problem because each of them has their own version of `n` that is unique to that call.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I attached this image that shows explanation in details
[image]